# QpushButtos com designes mais robustos

Tags: button, pyqt

Estou estudando PyQt5 e acho meio estranho o designe dos QpushButtons.
é possível colocar a descrição do botão no canto inferior e faze-lo mudar de cor quando o cursor está em cima dele ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

É possível sim! Para os estilos, há a função `.setStyleSheet()`

Para um estilo no botão, você pode escrever o código dessa forma:

```
btn.setStyleSheet("font: 15pt Arial;margin: 1px;
border-color: #0c457e; border-style: outset;
border-radius: 1px;border-width: 1px;color: white;
background-color:
qlineargradient(x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1, stop: 0 #2198c0, stop: 1 #0d5ca6);
}QPushButton:pressed
{ background-color: qlineargradient(x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1, stop: 0 #0d5ca6, stop: 1 #2198c0);")
```

Assim, o botão tem uma cor azul com gradiente quando normal e um novo estilo quando pressionado, com o a parte final do código:

```
QPushButton:pressed
    { background-color: qlineargradient(x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1, stop: 0 #0d5ca6, stop: 1 #2198c0);")
```

Para que o botão mude apenas com o mouse em cima, basta adicionar um código da seguinte forma:

```
btn.setStyleSheet("QPushButton:hover:!pressed {border: 1px solid red;}")
```

Lembrando que você pode alterar o estilo como bem entender, como no modelo:

```
QPushButton:hover:!pressed
{
  border: 1px solid red;        # Nesse exemplo, as bordas ficam vermelhas
  color: white;                 # O texto fica branco     
  background-color: black       # O fundo do botão fica preto
}
```

Para um texto quando o mouse está em cima do botão, deve-se adicionar uma ToolTip. Para isso, basta o código abaixo:

```
btn.setToolTip("Aqui vai a descrição do botão")
```

Comment: Muito obrigado por essa resposta completa, isso ajuda muito

Comment: mas que comando eu uso pra colocar o texto dentro do botão no canto inferior?

Comment: Você pode fazer assim: button.setStyleSheet("text-align: bottom") e o texto irá ficar no canto inferior do botão.

Comment: Muito Obrigado Guilherme

Comment: Por nada! Qualquer dúvida, só comentar aqui novamente.